# switch statement only runs once with mouse over listener

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, switch-statement, addeventlistener

when i move over the star icons, The handleselect function runs only once(the initial icon i moved over) it seems like the mouseover event only runs once but it doesn't. When i console.log(event.target.id) it outputs the id of the icon i moved over but runs handleselect(event.target.id) ) once

**html**
`

```
<section class="mx-lg-3 pt-lg-5 pb-5" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div id="confirm-box">{% include "message.html" %}</div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 mb-3">
                <img src="{{product.image.url}}" class="w-100" alt="product image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 product-details">
                <p class="sale text-center">Sale</p>
                <h2>{{product.name|title}}</h2>
                <p>Product id: {{product.id}}</p>
                <div class="ratings">
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="first"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="second"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="third"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="fourth"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star" id="fifth"></span>
                </div>
                <p class="product-price">USD ${{product.price}}</p>
                <label for="">Quantity: </label>
                <input type="text" readonly id="product-quantity" value="{{current_item.quantity}}">
                <button id="update-cart" data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn add-btn update-cart">Add to cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**javascript**

`

```
window.onload = function() {
  const one = document.getElementById('first')
  const two = document.getElementById('second')
  const three = document.getElementById('third')
  const four = document.getElementById('fourth')
  const five = document.getElementById('fifth')


  const handleselect = function(selection) {
    switch(selection) {
        case 'first': {
            one.classList.add('checked')
            two.classList.remove('checked')
            three.classList.remove('checked')
            four.classList.remove('checked')
            five.classList.remove('checked')
            return
        }
        case 'second': {
            one.classList.add('checked')
            two.classList.add('checked')
            three.classList.remove('checked')
            four.classList.remove('checked')
            five.classList.remove('checked')
            return
        }

        case 'third': {
            one.classList.add('checked')
            two.classList.add('checked')
            three.classList.add('checked')
            four.classList.remove('checked')
            five.classList.remove('checked')
            return
        }

        case 'fourth': {
            one.classList.add('checked')
            two.classList.add('checked')
            three.classList.add('checked')
            four.classList.add('checked')
            five.classList.remove('checked')
            return
        }

        case 'fifth': {
            one.classList.add('checked')
            two.classList.add('checked')
            three.classList.add('checked')
            four.classList.add('checked')
            five.classList.add('checked')
        }
    }
  }
  const arr = [one, two, three, four, five]


  arr.forEach(item=> item.addEventListener('mouseover', (event)=>{
    handleselect(event.target.id)
    // console.log(event.target.id)
  }))
}
```

i removed the return statement but it just runs everything till the fifth switch case instead of when the mouse moves over each case

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const one = document.getElementById('first')
  const two = document.getElementById('second')
  const three = document.getElementById('third')
  const four = document.getElementById('fourth')
  const five = document.getElementById('fifth')


  const handleselect = function(selection) {
    switch (selection) {
      case 'first':
        {
          one.classList.add('checked')
          two.classList.remove('checked')
          three.classList.remove('checked')
          four.classList.remove('checked')
          five.classList.remove('checked')
          return
        }
      case 'second':
        {
          one.classList.add('checked')
          two.classList.add('checked')
          three.classList.remove('checked')
          four.classList.remove('checked')
          five.classList.remove('checked')
          return
        }

      case 'third':
        {
          one.classList.add('checked')
          two.classList.add('checked')
          three.classList.add('checked')
          four.classList.remove('checked')
          five.classList.remove('checked')
          return
        }

      case 'fourth':
        {
          one.classList.add('checked')
          two.classList.add('checked')
          three.classList.add('checked')
          four.classList.add('checked')
          five.classList.remove('checked')
          return
        }

      case 'fifth':
        {
          one.classList.add('checked')
          two.classList.add('checked')
          three.classList.add('checked')
          four.classList.add('checked')
          five.classList.add('checked')
        }
    }
  }
  const arr = [one, two, three, four, five]


  arr.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    handleselect(event.target.id)
    // console.log(event.target.id)
  }))
}
```

```css
.checked {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ratings">
  <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="first"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="second"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="third"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="fourth"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" id="fifth"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine

Comment: For real? it's not working on my pc, could it be the browser?

Comment: It sounds like you were getting an error in the console

Comment: there's no error in the console